# How to get the length of an array of posts matching meta_query in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called 'service-area'. On one of the pages in particular, I am trying using a meta query to filter out the posts that it gets. That works fine.

I then use:

```
$serv_areas = get_posts($args);
```

Once again, I am able to get these posts without an issue using a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($serv_areas as $post) {...}
```

But I am having a different issue. I would like to get the amount of posts that match the meta query. But when I use

```
sizeof($serv_areas) or count($serv_areas)
```

I get the total amount of posts, not just the posts that meet the criteria.

How is this possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The `get_posts()` function returns a WP_Query.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties

In that case, you should use the property `$serv_areas->found_posts`

> **$found_posts**
>
> The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, $serv_areas->found_posts doesn't seem to be returning anything.

Comment: Or at least, nothing is showing when I do <?php echo $serv_areas->found_posts; ?>